# Centre image in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm calling a `JSQMessageViewController` and adding an image as the title but it's not centred due to the offset caused by the `Back` left-button.

[image]

Here's my code for adding the image:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame.size.width = 40
    imageView.frame.size.height = 40
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "avatar_example")
    imageView.image = image
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the problem is in JSQMessageViewController? Maybe you just need to use standard sizes from title view (44*44) for alignment.

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "avatar_example"))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    imageView.frame = titleView.bounds
    titleView.addSubview(imageView)

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually get the width and height of the `UINavigationBar` and center the image accordingly. Try this

```
    guard let bar = navigationController.navigationBar else { return }
    let bannerWidth = bar.frame.size.width
    let bannerHeight = bar.frame.size.height

    // centers image vertically & horizontally
    let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - imageView.frame.width / 2
    let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - imageView.frame.height / 2

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    navigationItem.titleView = logoImageView
```